# Is there a way to recommend someone for wider Stack Exchange infractions?

Tags: feature-request

Hypothetically, if a user has decided to troll the philosophy stack exchange with (say) personal harassment and deliberately aggressive answers, but has an active presence on other, non-philosophy SE sites, is there an action pathway whereby a response might be taken across the SE network against their account to reflect their misconduct here?

Comment: like, don't take this the wrong way, but it's not me is it? i thought i was just an *unpopular* user of this site, though i am psychotic

Comment: Don’t worry, it’s just a hypothetical.  Or, at least, the meta point is hypothetical, and I don’t think you’re specifically harassing anyone? Taking the fifth is probably wise, at any rate!